# Play audio onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple website I am trying to build. I have a mp4 video (it is a sign no audio)
I want to click the video and have it play an mp3 w/ controls. Just cannot figure out how to do this.

Assume I could use something like this:

```
    <audio controls id="linkAudio">
  <source src="demo.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="demo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<script>
  document.getElementById("link_id").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("linkAudio").play();
  });
</script>
```

But where do I reference the video src as the thing to click?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean video src as the thing to click? Clarify or post a example fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the `<video>` separate and on `click` event trigger the audio.

```js
document.getElementById("link_id").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("linkAudio").play();
});
```

```css
video{
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<video src='http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4' id='link_id'></video>

<audio controls id="linkAudio">
  <source src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/29.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: That works perfectly thanks. Is there a way to put the controls onscreen only after the onclick event? If I add controls to the audio tag it shows before you click the audio.

Comment: @scopa I would implement custom video controls to do so and not use the default ones. Please refer to my GitHub repo here: http://rahul-desai3.github.io/video_player/#demo